# Separating two print() outputs under a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

> Question:  Enter a value for *n*, and the code takes *n* floating
> numbers and prints out the first highest and second-highest numbers.

Sample Output 1:

```
Enter number of real numbers: 5
Number#1: 45.23
Number#2: 23.5
Number#3: 12
Number#4: 12.321
Number#5: 105.5
The first highest number is 105.5
The second-highest number is 45.23
```

Sample Output 2:

```
Enter number of real numbers: 1
Number#1: 100.275
The first highest number is 105.5
There is no second highest number.
```

My code:

```
n = int(input("Enter number of real numbers: "))
ctr = 0
firsth = 0
secondh = 0

if n == 1:
    temp = float(input(f"Number#{ctr+1}: "))
    firsth = temp
    print(f"The first highest number is {firsth} \nThere is no second highest number. \n")
while ctr < n and n != 1:
    temp = float(input(f"Number#{ctr+1}: "))
    ctr += 1
    if temp > firsth: 
        secondh = firsth
        firsth = temp
    elif temp > secondh:
        secondh = temp
    print(f"The first highest number is {firsth} \nThe second highest number is {secondh} \n")
```

I tried several times that my code will eventually print both outputs of when `n == 1` and of the `while`-loop. Any idea on how to print only one output when `n == 1`?

Comment: Change your code for the `n == 1` case to just print one output. i.e. `print(f"The highest number is {firsth}`)`.

Comment: @martineau It's still not the ideal output, I think the problem might be the conditions I set for the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the while loop under else statement. It will not execute as long as n==1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for the helpful tip, I've modified my code and it's getting the idea results now.

Answer (score 1):

if i understand your question properly, this should work.

```
n = int(input("Enter number of real numbers: "))
nums = []

for i in range(n):
    nums.append(float(input(f"Number#{i+1}: ")))
    
nums.sort()

l = ['first', 'second']

for i in range(0,n):
    if i>1:
        break
    
    print(f'{l[i]} highest number is: {nums[-(i+1)]} ')
else:
    print('There is no second highest number')
    
"""
Enter number of real numbers: 5

Number#1: 100

Number#2: 20

Number#3: 50

Number#4: 60

Number#5: 11
first highest number is: 100.0 
second highest number is: 60.0 
"""

"""
Enter number of real numbers: 1

Number#1: 10
first highest number is: 10.0 
There is no second highest number
"""
```

Comment: Any idea how to do this with a while-loop?